# Display modal with information from a specific button

Tags: javascript, django

I have a Django template that renders a little bit of data about the user.  It is a for list that goes through and creates this element for each user.  I want to be able to click on that and have a modal appear with all of their information.  So if I click on user1  I get user1's information, and so on.  I am not sure how to do this.

I am currently trying to use JavaScript to do this.  The problem is that I cannot get the data from the specific element into JavaScript.  I have the modal working, in that it pops up.  However, I cannot find a way to retrieve the data from the specific user clicked on.

```
#dashboard.html
{% for party in parties %}
    <div class="userInfo">
        <img user="{{party}}" src="{% static 'restaurants/images/userIcon.png' %}">
        <div class="userText">
            <p>{{party.lastName}} </p></br>
        </div>
        <button name="remove"><a href="/restaurants/removeParty/{{party.id}}">Remove</a></button>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

I just need to get data from a specific user into the js from the specifc button clicked.  Maybe there is a better way to do this?  I am not sure.  I just need be able to populate a modal with data from the specific user clicked.  The above code shows the html for the loop that creates the user info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be a bit verbose depending on how large your object is but you could use data attributes:

```
{% for party in parties %}
    <div class="userInfo" data-lastName="{{party.lastName}}" data-etc="{{party.etc}}">
        <img user="{{party}}" src="{% static 'restaurants/images/userIcon.png' %}">
        <div class="userText">
            <p>{{party.lastName}} </p></br>
        </div>
        <button name="remove"><a href="/restaurants/removeParty/{{party.id}}">Remove</a></button>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

and then just access them when you click to open the modal:

```
const users = document.querySelectorAll('.userInfo');

for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
  users[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    const userData = {
           lastName: this.dataset.lastName,
           etc: this.dataset.etc
        }
    openMyModal(userData);
  })
}
})
```

Comment: When I do this, I get "this.dataset is undefined"  Am I missing something here?

Comment: My bad, I used an arrow function and forgot to loop through the node list.  I updated it and made an example [here](https://codepen.io/extrachrisb/pen/xvqVdv)

Comment: Alright, well this is working, so thank you.  However, I am getting numbers,  When I console.log I get "NaN".  When I console.log() the typeof, it says number.  Any idea on this one?

Comment: Try inspecting the generated HTML and make sure you've got the right data in the attributes.  If it is and you're doing math with it, you may need to cast it as a number using ```parseInt()``` or ```Number()```.

Comment: Checked it, the data is correct in the generated HTML.  And no math.  I am dealing only with strings here.

Comment: Also, FYI.  I looked it up and you can't use uppercase for the variable name in the HTML.  Though that isn't my problem.

Comment: Strange, I'd have to see the code, it should log whatever is inside the attribute.  You can try using ```this.getAttribute('data-x`)``` instead, but either way should work.  And what is uppercased?

Comment: I'll give that a try.  In the HTML above you have 'data-lastName', it has to be lowercase.

Comment: According to the docs  "Variable names consist of any combination of alphanumeric characters and the underscore ("_") but may not start with an underscore," but honestly I'm not that familiar with Django

Comment: I read something that said that said that the variable couldn't contain uppercase.  Now I can't find it again.  However, getAttribute() worked for me.  I tried some uppercase and that works too.  So thanks a lot for all of your help!